# How get Zabbix status flag for "calculated" field item?

Tags: zabbix

How get value of flag "The item is not discovered anymore and will be deleted" in lld item?
Need it to replace item value to "0".

Comment: we_dont_do_that_here.jpg , seriously, that item can't have values because is not being discovered anymore, and if it's not being discovered it likely means it doesn't exist anymore in the monitored host

Answer (score 0):

That 'flag' is not item data, so it cannot be calculated. May as well just manually delete it. The underlying issue (why has the item disappeared?) may be something to shift focus to.

Comment: I need to set '0' as int number, because it's an speccific lld sql-request, and it can't return '0'.